# Delete everything in a line except the first whitespace characters

Tags: vim

Say I have these lines in Vim:

```
void CSSdescramble(unsigned char *sec,unsigned char *key) {
  unsigned int t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6;
```

And say the cursor is somewhere in the middle of the second line. How can I delete everything on that line except for the two leading spaces?

I can do it with `^d$`, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: Close your eyes and imagine for a minute how you would do it in a "normal" editor. Once you are done, ask yourself: "Do I *really* need a more efficient way than `^d$`?"

Comment: Maybe not, but asking about trivial improvements has led me to learn things that have made me quite a bit more efficient, so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, the easiest way is to use `cc`, if you wish to type something new instead of deleted line. Otherwise `^D`.

Comment: could be shorter than `cc` :-)

Comment: `S` is one character but two keystrokes. `cc` is faster for me, but maybe it depends on how you type.

Answer (score 1):

`C` (shift-c) has the same effect as `d$a`, deleting the rest of the line and putting you into insert mode (the question asked about `^d$a` when I first answered it). Or `D` does the same as `d$` without the `a`.

Answer (score 1):

golf a bit:

try with single `S` (big S in normal mode), if you don't care switching to `insert` mode.

otherwise, use others answer  `^D` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1281385 pointed out, you can use `D` — which deletes from the cursor to the end of the line — to save a keystroke.

If you want to keep the whitespace at the beginning of the line, I don’t think there’s a way around `^`.